# Failed Because T-SQL And CLR Types For Return Value Do Not Match When using Task<string>

Tags: c#, t-sql

I'm getting error when using `Task<string>` as return type. When testing with `string` as return type it works.

The function which only returns `string` works, but the function which returns `Task<string>` does not work

Is there any workaround?

c# code

```
    public async static Task<string> LagreFil(string filNavn, string 
        filePath, string url) {

        var fileService = new FileService();
        return await fileService.LagreFilAsync(filNavn, filePath, url);
    }
      public static string LagreFilTest() {
        return "suksess";
    }
```

sql code

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY CL2
FROM 
'C:\xxx.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET unSAFE 
GO 

alter FUNCTION fnTEST2() RETURNS nvarchar(max)
EXTERNAL NAME CL2.[Tools.Files.library.Api.AttachmentsService].LagreFilTest;
select qq = dbo.fnTEST2()
```

Comment: Could you please post the code that succeeds and the code that fails ? Thanks

Comment: Post your code, and also error message.

Comment: You didn't post any information so it's impossible to guess what the bug in the code is. The only thing that's certain is that there's a bug in the code - you're using one type when you should be using another. Perhaps you forgot to `await` a call to `ExecuteScalarAsync` or something similar?

Comment: Using `Task<string>` as a return type won't make a method run in the background by magic anyway. It *will* result in a type mismatch compilation error if you try to return `string` though.  Adding the `async` keyword will hide the error but still run synchronously. Without the code one can only guess what the problem is and how to fix it - if you don't want async execution replace `Task<string>` with `string`. If you *do* want it, use `async Task<string>` in the signature *and* `await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync` to execute the query and get the result.

Comment: Hi, I have tested that the function works from c#. The problem is when calling it from SQL. I have added code

Comment: SQL CLR has no support for `async` whatsoever. The "workaround" is to not use it. To synchronously wait on an `async` result, you can use `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`.

Comment: Yes, looks like it... ended up using https://github.com/tejacques/AsyncBridge
If you add as answer I will mark it as correct.